# accessing "isValid" inside "validateForm" function returns wrong data (manual formik validation)

Tags: react-native, expo, formik, yup

### Context

Have my own implementation of mult-step "formik" form in react native ( expo app).  i want to validate only on button press(manual validation). if form is valid then proceed to next form step.

#### Problem:

Right now  wrong value of "isValid" inside "validateForm" dot then function is creating problem to implement my logic.

also calling  validateForm function is rendering fork form multiple times... i guess it might be due to formik internally changing the states. But the problem is if we check errors object it has empty object in one render and different object in another render ( basically i could use error length to implement multi step form switching... no luck in that too).

```
 Problem code link: https://snack.expo.io/@rosnk/formik-submit-test
```

#### Expected behavior

1. want proper "isValid" value inside validateForm().then() function when promise has been resolved

#### environment

| Software | Version(s) |
| --- | --- |
| Formik | "^2.2.6" |
| React | "16.13.1", |
| npm/Yarn | npm |
| Operating System | mac |

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having inconsistent values because you are using the isValid that is passed on as a parameter and that value doesn't change after validateForm().

In your handleCustomSubmit function, try using

```
const handleCustomSubmit = (validateForm, isValid)=>{
  console.log("custom submit")
  validateForm().then((errors) => {        
    console.log("validation complete");
    console.log("errors are", errors)   
  });
}
```

If the errors object is empty, it should be valid.